# Alternative to polling for failed XHR requests to check internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

I am using the following script to constantly poll the server every 2 seconds to check if the user is connected to VPN.

```
var uiBlocked = false;
window.setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'HEAD',
  url: '/heartbeat/',
  timeout: 1000,
  success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
   if (uiBlocked == true && navigator.onLine) {
      uiBlocked = false;
      $.unblockUI();
     }
   },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus != 'timeout'){
       if (uiBlocked == false){
         uiBlocked = true;
         $.blockUI({
           message: "Lost connectivity, please reconnect your VPN.",
           css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
          } });
     }
   }
 }
})
}, 2000);
```

The problem is that the constant polling has brought the PROD server down yesterday. Is there an alternative to this that I can use here to do this more effectively.

Comment: Why do you need to poll? cant you instead just react to a failure when you attempt to do something that requires the server? would probably cause a hell of a lot less stress. Imagine 20-30 people (or a lot more than that!) locking their PC but leaving it running overnight. all that wasted bandwidth/resources!

Comment: The main issue is likely the fact that you're using setInterval instead of setTimeout. setInterval will continue to poll regardless of whether or not the server has finished handling the request (just because the client stopped listening for a response doesn't mean the server isn't still processing it anyway)

Comment: Ideally I would like to go on a path where I do not need to poll , but that would require a long process of refactoring etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would both decrease the polling rate and make sure the server isn't creating a new connection for every request.

You don't mention what type of server it is but the setting should be called KeepAlive on all servers. Besides that maybe look into why the server went down?

Comment: I have added that header to my ajax request now. The response shows Connection: keep-alive . Is that fine

Comment: Without knowing what server you're running it is impossible to know for sure. Perhaps you should ask the people who are running the server?

Comment: Also I am using HTTP/1.1 so the Keep-Alive is happening anyways. I will look into the reasons why the server went down.